# Height 100% with two divs using float left and right (with clear)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is very simple:

HTML:

```
    <div>
        <section class="left">

        </section>
        <section class="right">

        </section>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div, section { border: 1px solid #000; }
.left { height: 100%; width: 200px; float: left; height: 200px; }
.right { width: 300px; float: right; height: 300px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/H2c6g/

How I do for the div use the 100% of height?

Comment: your question is not clear at all . please clarify

Comment: I don't understand what your question means. Which `div` do you want to use 100% of what height?

Comment: Just for fun, no floats. You get the idea ;) http://jsfiddle.net/fTf52/

Comment: Also, <section> should not be used as a wrapper

Answer (score 1):

You can use `width: 100%` on the inner `<section>`s as long as you also define a height on the wrapping `<div>`.  Try this CSS:

```
div { height: 400px; background: #ccc; }
.left { height: 100%; width: 200px; float: left; background: #c00; }
.right { width: 300px; float: right; height: 300px; background: #00c; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H2c6g/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And make the `div`'s `height: 100%`

As seen in this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2c6g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not sure if this is what you are trying to do

```
<div class="outer">
        <section class="left">

        </section>
        <section class="right">

        </section>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


div, section { border: 1px solid #000; }
.left { height: 100%; width: 200px; float: left; height: 200px; }
.right { width: 300px; float: right; height: 300px; }
.clear { clear: both; }

div.outer{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox if you don't need to support older IE browsers.... Check it out below.

display:flex

Notice that I am only setting a height for the .left class the .right class matches the height.

http://jsbin.com/curoruni/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, not using any floats

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

And

```
#wrapper { 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
.left { 
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%; width: 50%; 
    margin: 0px;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 50%; height: 100%; 
    margin: 0px;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/fU379/**